# Change Value Numeric Format in DevExpress WebChartControl

Tags: devexpress, webchartcontrol

I want to change Value Numeric Format on point label in WebChartControl Series Template. For example, my value on the point is "20.1003435434", and I would set it as "20.10" . I tried to set numericOptions format = "Currency" and Precision="0". But I couldn't be successfull. Thats my code :

```
<dxchartsui:WebChartControl ID="WebChartControl" runat="server" DataSourceID="ASPxPivotGrid" Height="300px" SeriesDataMember="Series" Width="900px" Visible="False">
        <diagramserializable>
            <cc2:XYDiagram>
                <axisx title-text="Gün" visibleinpanesserializable="-1">
                    <range sidemarginsenabled="True" />
                    <numericoptions format="General" />
                </axisx>
                <axisy title-text="Değer" visibleinpanesserializable="-1">
                    <range sidemarginsenabled="True" />
                    <numericoptions  Format="Currency" Precision="0" />
                </axisy>
            </cc2:XYDiagram>
        </diagramserializable>
        <fillstyle>
            <OptionsSerializable>
                <cc1:SolidFillOptions></cc1:SolidFillOptions>
            </OptionsSerializable>
        </fillstyle>
        <legend maxhorizontalpercentage="30"></legend>
        <seriestemplate argumentdatamember="Arguments" argumentscaletype="Qualitative" valuedatamembersserializable="Values">
            <ViewSerializable>
                <cc1:LineSeriesView><LineMarkerOptions Visible="True"></LineMarkerOptions></cc1:LineSeriesView>
            </ViewSerializable>
            <LabelSerializable>
                <cc1:PointSeriesLabel LineVisible="True">
                    <fillstyle>
                        <optionsserializable><cc1:SolidFillOptions /></optionsserializable>
                    </fillstyle>
                    <pointoptionsserializable>
                        <cc1:PointOptions><ArgumentNumericOptions Format="Currency" Precision="1"></ArgumentNumericOptions><ValueNumericOptions Format="Currency" Precision="1"></ValueNumericOptions></cc1:PointOptions>
                    </pointoptionsserializable>
                </cc1:PointSeriesLabel>
            </LabelSerializable>
            <LegendPointOptionsSerializable>
                <cc1:PointOptions><ArgumentNumericOptions Format="Currency" Precision="1"></ArgumentNumericOptions><ValueNumericOptions Format="Currency" Precision="1"></ValueNumericOptions></cc1:PointOptions>
            </LegendPointOptionsSerializable>
        </seriestemplate>
        <crosshairoptions>
            <CommonLabelPositionSerializable>
                <cc1:CrosshairMousePosition></cc1:CrosshairMousePosition>
            </CommonLabelPositionSerializable>
        </crosshairoptions>
        <tooltipoptions>
            <ToolTipPositionSerializable>
                <cc1:ToolTipMousePosition></cc1:ToolTipMousePosition>
            </ToolTipPositionSerializable>
        </tooltipoptions>
    </dxchartsui:WebChartControl>
```

There is screenshot below link:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **CrosshairLabelPattern="{V:0.##}"** attribute into **seriestemplate** tag